# Ask User to Input IP, FQDN, or Hostname then Resolve/Verify

Tags: python-3.x

I'm confused on how I could prompt the user for an IP, FQDN, or hostname.  Either I want to use the IP address they entered (check to see if it's valid first), lookup the IP with the FQDN, or get the FQDN using the hostname (using local DNS settings).

```
ipaddress = input(ipaddress.ip_address(f"Enter IP, FQDN, or Host: ")
```

I'm not sure how I could go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a bracket so it should be

```
import ipaddress

ipaddress = input(ipaddress.ip_address(f"Enter IP, FQDN, or Host: "))
```

I dont know why u made it a f string but